# Second RAM module is not shown in `free` in Manjaro

Tags: arch-linux, ram, manjaro

I have two RAM modules (8 GB each) but there is only one shown in `free`. I need to find a solution:

```
$ uname -srvmo
Linux 3.10.27-1-MANJARO #1 SMP Sat Jan 18 09:42:13 UTC 2014 x86_64 GNU/Linux

$ free -m
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:          6840       6336        503         49         74        467
-/+ buffers/cache:       5794       1046
Swap:         7003       3233       3770

# dmidecode 2.12
SMBIOS 2.7 present.
17 structures occupying 1060 bytes.
Table at 0x000EBF50.

Handle 0x0000, DMI type 0, 24 bytes
BIOS Information
    Vendor: American Megatrends Inc.
    Version: P2.10
    Release Date: 01/17/2014
    Address: 0xF0000
    Runtime Size: 64 kB
    ROM Size: 8192 kB
    Characteristics:
        PCI is supported
        BIOS is upgradeable
        BIOS shadowing is allowed
        Boot from CD is supported
        Selectable boot is supported
        BIOS ROM is socketed
        EDD is supported
        5.25"/1.2 MB floppy services are supported (int 13h)
        3.5"/720 kB floppy services are supported (int 13h)
        3.5"/2.88 MB floppy services are supported (int 13h)
        Print screen service is supported (int 5h)
        8042 keyboard services are supported (int 9h)
        Serial services are supported (int 14h)
        Printer services are supported (int 17h)
        ACPI is supported
        USB legacy is supported
        BIOS boot specification is supported
        Targeted content distribution is supported
        UEFI is supported
    BIOS Revision: 4.6

Handle 0x0001, DMI type 1, 27 bytes
System Information
    Manufacturer: To Be Filled By O.E.M.
    Product Name: To Be Filled By O.E.M.
    Version: To Be Filled By O.E.M.
    Serial Number: To Be Filled By O.E.M.
    UUID: 03000200-0400-0500-0006-000700080009
    Wake-up Type: Power Switch
    SKU Number: To Be Filled By O.E.M.
    Family: To Be Filled By O.E.M.

Handle 0x0002, DMI type 2, 15 bytes
Base Board Information
    Manufacturer: ASRock
    Product Name: FM2A88X-ITX+
    Version:                       
    Serial Number: E80-3B005600472
    Asset Tag:                       
    Features:
        Board is a hosting board
        Board is replaceable
    Location In Chassis:                       
    Chassis Handle: 0x0003
    Type: Motherboard
    Contained Object Handles: 0

Handle 0x0003, DMI type 3, 22 bytes
Chassis Information
    Manufacturer: To Be Filled By O.E.M.
    Type: Desktop
    Lock: Not Present
    Version: To Be Filled By O.E.M.
    Serial Number: To Be Filled By O.E.M.
    Asset Tag: To Be Filled By O.E.M.
    Boot-up State: Safe
    Power Supply State: Safe
    Thermal State: Safe
    Security Status: None
    OEM Information: 0x00000000
    Height: Unspecified
    Number Of Power Cords: 1
    Contained Elements: 0
    SKU Number: To be filled by O.E.M.

Handle 0x0004, DMI type 9, 17 bytes
System Slot Information
    Designation: PCIE1
    Type: x16 PCI Express
    Current Usage: In Use
    Length: Short
    ID: 17
    Characteristics:
        3.3 V is provided
        Opening is shared
        PME signal is supported
    Bus Address: 0000:00:15.0

Handle 0x0005, DMI type 11, 5 bytes
OEM Strings
    String 1: To Be Filled By O.E.M.

Handle 0x0006, DMI type 7, 19 bytes
Cache Information
    Socket Designation: L1 CACHE
    Configuration: Enabled, Not Socketed, Level 1
    Operational Mode: Write Back
    Location: Internal
    Installed Size: 256 kB
    Maximum Size: 256 kB
    Supported SRAM Types:
        Pipeline Burst
    Installed SRAM Type: Pipeline Burst
    Speed: 1 ns
    Error Correction Type: Multi-bit ECC
    System Type: Unified
    Associativity: 2-way Set-associative

Handle 0x0007, DMI type 7, 19 bytes
Cache Information
    Socket Designation: L2 CACHE
    Configuration: Enabled, Not Socketed, Level 2
    Operational Mode: Write Back
    Location: Internal
    Installed Size: 4096 kB
    Maximum Size: 4096 kB
    Supported SRAM Types:
        Pipeline Burst
    Installed SRAM Type: Pipeline Burst
    Speed: 1 ns
    Error Correction Type: Multi-bit ECC
    System Type: Unified
    Associativity: 16-way Set-associative

Handle 0x000C, DMI type 32, 20 bytes
System Boot Information
    Status: No errors detected

Handle 0x000E, DMI type 16, 23 bytes
Physical Memory Array
    Location: System Board Or Motherboard
    Use: System Memory
    Error Correction Type: None
    Maximum Capacity: 16 GB
    Error Information Handle: Not Provided
    Number Of Devices: 2

Handle 0x000F, DMI type 19, 31 bytes
Memory Array Mapped Address
    Starting Address: 0x00000000000
    Ending Address: 0x003FFFFFFFF
    Range Size: 16 GB
    Physical Array Handle: 0x000E
    Partition Width: 255

Handle 0x0010, DMI type 17, 34 bytes
Memory Device
    Array Handle: 0x000E
    Error Information Handle: Not Provided
    Total Width: 64 bits
    Data Width: 64 bits
    Size: 8192 MB
    Form Factor: DIMM
    Set: None
    Locator: DIMM 0
    Bank Locator: CHANNEL A
    Type: DDR3
    Type Detail: Synchronous Unbuffered (Unregistered)
    Speed: 1600 MHz
    Manufacturer: <BAD INDEX>
    Serial Number: 00000000
    Asset Tag: A1_AssetTagNum0
    Part Number: CMV8GX3M1A1600C11 
    Rank: 2
    Configured Clock Speed: 1600 MHz

Handle 0x0011, DMI type 20, 35 bytes
Memory Device Mapped Address
    Starting Address: 0x00000000000
    Ending Address: 0x001FFFFFFFF
    Range Size: 8 GB
    Physical Device Handle: 0x0010
    Memory Array Mapped Address Handle: 0x000F
    Partition Row Position: 1

Handle 0x0012, DMI type 17, 34 bytes
Memory Device
    Array Handle: 0x000E
    Error Information Handle: Not Provided
    Total Width: 64 bits
    Data Width: 64 bits
    Size: 8192 MB
    Form Factor: DIMM
    Set: None
    Locator: DIMM 0
    Bank Locator: CHANNEL B
    Type: DDR3
    Type Detail: Synchronous Unbuffered (Unregistered)
    Speed: 1600 MHz
    Manufacturer: <BAD INDEX>
    Serial Number: 00000000
    Asset Tag: A1_AssetTagNum1
    Part Number: CMV8GX3M1A1600C11 
    Rank: 2
    Configured Clock Speed: 1600 MHz

Handle 0x0013, DMI type 20, 35 bytes
Memory Device Mapped Address
    Starting Address: 0x00200000000
    Ending Address: 0x003FFFFFFFF
    Range Size: 8 GB
    Physical Device Handle: 0x0012
    Memory Array Mapped Address Handle: 0x000F
    Partition Row Position: 1

Handle 0x0016, DMI type 4, 42 bytes
Processor Information
    Socket Designation: CPUSocket
    Type: Central Processor
    Family: A-Series
    Manufacturer: AMD
    ID: 01 0F 63 00 FF FB 8B 17
    Signature: Family 21, Model 48, Stepping 1
    Flags:
        FPU (Floating-point unit on-chip)
        VME (Virtual mode extension)
        DE (Debugging extension)
        PSE (Page size extension)
        TSC (Time stamp counter)
        MSR (Model specific registers)
        PAE (Physical address extension)
        MCE (Machine check exception)
        CX8 (CMPXCHG8 instruction supported)
        APIC (On-chip APIC hardware supported)
        SEP (Fast system call)
        MTRR (Memory type range registers)
        PGE (Page global enable)
        MCA (Machine check architecture)
        CMOV (Conditional move instruction supported)
        PAT (Page attribute table)
        PSE-36 (36-bit page size extension)
        CLFSH (CLFLUSH instruction supported)
        MMX (MMX technology supported)
        FXSR (FXSAVE and FXSTOR instructions supported)
        SSE (Streaming SIMD extensions)
        SSE2 (Streaming SIMD extensions 2)
        HTT (Multi-threading)
    Version: AMD A10-7850K APU with Radeon(TM) R7 Graphics  
    Voltage: 1.4 V
    External Clock: 100 MHz
    Max Speed: 4000 MHz
    Current Speed: 4000 MHz
    Status: Populated, Enabled
    Upgrade: Socket FM2
    L1 Cache Handle: 0x0006
    L2 Cache Handle: 0x0007
    L3 Cache Handle: Not Provided
    Serial Number: Not Specified
    Asset Tag: Not Specified
    Part Number: Not Specified
    Core Count: 4
    Core Enabled: 4
    Thread Count: 4
    Characteristics:
        64-bit capable

Handle 0x0017, DMI type 127, 4 bytes
End Of Table
```

Comment: Actually looking at the `dmidecode` output, it looks like you have two 8GB sticks installed (Type 17 entries in `dmidecode`) but `free` is only showing 8GB. Is that your question? If so, you may want to change the word "occupied" to "showing in free"

Comment: Yes it is. `free` showing only 8GB (actually 7, because, as far as I know, 1GB is used by processor's graphics)

Answer (score 0):

As I've found, the problem was related to motherboard ASRock FM2A88X-ITX+. I've replaced it by warranty, but after half of a year of usage the problem was reproduced by a new one.

*The further story is: I've bought another motherboard, and when I bring ASRock, that was resting for a month, to the warranty center, it was found, that it works Ok again.*